# Android studio firebase query . I only want the student and child with the same uid to display

Tags: java, android, firebase

[Relevant image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Gul9.jpg)

final FirebaseUser fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Students");

```
    final DatabaseReference refOne = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");



    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            userList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                ModelUser modelUser = ds.getValue(ModelUser.class);



                {
                    userList.add(modelUser);
                }

                //adapter
                adapterUsers = new AdapterUser(Parent_LoginActivity.this, userList);
                //set adapter to recyclerview
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterUsers);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Tell us what is the expected result.

Comment: I can see all at the moment, i only want to see results with the same uid from student and user,I have added a pic of my database

Comment: The code should go before {
                    userList.add(modelUser);
                }

Comment: Do you have in `User` node only partents or students as well?

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: Please rephrase this: " i only want to see results with the same uid from student and user"

Comment: No problem.With the current code i am able to see all the students in my recyclerview.i want to filter it to only show the student where the student uid matches the logged in user uid.

Comment: Either change your firebase hierarchy (structure) in which `uid` is the main key and `student` and `User` are its values or another way is  retrive and store **both student and User** in arrays/lists and then loop both the arrays one inside another but that would be an inefficient  way to do if you have huge data

Comment: @Revesh can you please elaborate about your application so that we can suggest some better solutions :)

Comment: I have managed to sort it out,Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You might need to retrieve the data first and insert them to list and then compare and retrieve the data you want. Firebase method can't do much on query as good as SQL.